# Is bitter gourd permitted to be used in Devi alankar?

Tags: devi

In Navaratri, Devi is decorated with alankara (ornaments, garlands) made of vegetables. Is the vegetable bitter gourd permitted?

Comment: It will be hard to find reference for this.

Comment: Chapter 28, book 7 of Devi Bhagavatam says Vegetables but it doesn't mention specific names. But finding explicit reference for Bitter gourd is difficult. It looks like bitter gourd is not used, at least in Kanaka Durga temple of Vijayawada. See [here](http://www.kanakadurgatemple.org/SHAKAMBARI_UTSAVAMS.aspx).